# How to Extract Data from Arrays Within Arrays

Tags: json, csv, parsing, jq, data-extraction

I have the JSON:

```
{
  "count": 6918,
  "next": "https://otx.alienvault.com/api/v1/pulses/subscribed?limit=50&page=2",
  "results": [
    {
      "industries": [],
      "tlp": "white",
      "description": "With the massive ransomware campaigns of 2016 and 2017 taking a backseat to bankers and other malware families, information stealers made up 18% of malicious email payloads in the first part of this year. Proofpoint researchers recently discovered a new stealer, dubbed “Nocturnal Stealer,” most notable as an example of inexpensive commodity malware with significant potential for monetization.\n\nOn March 9, a user posted an advertisement for Nocturnal Stealer on an underground forum. The stealer sold for 1500 Rubles, or roughly US$25 at the time of analysis. Nocturnal Stealer is designed to steal the data found within multiple Chromium and Firefox based browsers. It can also steal many popular cryptocurrency wallets as well as any saved FTP passwords within FileZilla. Proofpoint researchers analyzed a sample being dropped in the wild by an unknown loader.",
      "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:14.636000",
      "tags": [],
      "modified": "2018-05-31T12:25:14.636000",
      "author_name": "AlienVault",
      "public": 1,
      "extract_source": [],
      "references": [
        "https://www.proofpoint.com/us/threat-insight/post/thief-night-new-nocturnal-stealer-grabs-data-cheap"
      ],
      "targeted_countries": [],
      "indicators": [
        {
          "indicator": "http://nctrnl.us/",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "URL",
          "id": 981584318
        },
        {
          "indicator": "http://nctrnl.us/ara.exe",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "URL",
          "id": 981584319
        },
        {
          "indicator": "http://nctrnl.us/ark.exe",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "URL",
          "id": 981584320
        },
        {
          "indicator": "c9a834dde38c8b559d575ac61046e3a3fada97d2953d902b74cf8d5e51ada30f",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "FileHash-SHA256",
          "id": 981584321
        },
        {
          "indicator": "nctrnl.us",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "domain",
          "id": 981584322
        },
        {
          "indicator": "205def439aeb685d5a9123613e49f59d4cd5ebab9e933a1567a2f2972bda18c3",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "FileHash-SHA256",
          "id": 981584323
        },
        {
          "indicator": "ae7e5a7b34dc216e9da384fcf9868ab2c1a1d731f583f893b2d2d4009da15a4e",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "FileHash-SHA256",
          "id": 981584324
        },
        {
          "indicator": "http://nctrnl.us/server/gate.php",
          "description": "",
          "created": "2018-05-31T12:25:16",
          "title": "",
          "content": "",
          "type": "URL",
          "id": 981584325
        }
      ],
      "more_indicators": false,
      "revision": 1,
      "adversary": "",
      "id": "5b0fe9aa8bc6a5498565929a",
      "name": "Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The main array is `results` and I would like to pull the field `name` and then the fields `indicator` and `type` from the `indicators` array.

I have used the JQ command:

```
$ jq -r '.results[] | [.name] | .indicators[] | [.type, .indicator] | @csv' \
    < /home/threat-intel/ThreatIntel/AV.json \
    >> /home/threat-intel/ThreatIntel/AV.csv
```

The command fails saying:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "indicators"
```

How would I pull the `name` field and assign it to each `indicator` in that specific array?

Answer (score 1):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.results[] | .name as $n | .indicators[] | [$n, .type, .indicator] | @csv' file.json
```

The output:

```
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/ara.exe"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/ark.exe"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","FileHash-SHA256","c9a834dde38c8b559d575ac61046e3a3fada97d2953d902b74cf8d5e51ada30f"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","domain","nctrnl.us"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","FileHash-SHA256","205def439aeb685d5a9123613e49f59d4cd5ebab9e933a1567a2f2972bda18c3"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","FileHash-SHA256","ae7e5a7b34dc216e9da384fcf9868ab2c1a1d731f583f893b2d2d4009da15a4e"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/server/gate.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

`[.name]` is an array, and so when you pipe it into `.indicators`, you get the error message:

> Cannot index array with string "indicators"

This variation of your query is probably what you intended:

```
.results[]
| .name as $name 
| .indicators[]
| [$name, .type, .indicator] | @csv
```

This includes the relevant `.name` on each line:

```
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/ara.exe"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/ark.exe"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","FileHash-SHA256","c9a834dde38c8b559d575ac61046e3a3fada97d2953d902b74cf8d5e51ada30f"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","domain","nctrnl.us"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","FileHash-SHA256","205def439aeb685d5a9123613e49f59d4cd5ebab9e933a1567a2f2972bda18c3"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","FileHash-SHA256","ae7e5a7b34dc216e9da384fcf9868ab2c1a1d731f583f893b2d2d4009da15a4e"
"Thief in the night: New Nocturnal Stealer grabs data on the cheap","URL","http://nctrnl.us/server/gate.php"
```

Comment: is there a significant difference except `$name` and `$n` from the previous answer?

Comment: My answer: `answered 32 mins ago`, yours : `answered 28 mins ago`

Comment: We evidently worked on the response at about the same time.  If you reformat your answer so it can be read without scrolling horizontally, I'll delete mine.

Comment: "scrolling horizontally" acts on output only (also on your output). The command itself doesn't provoke scrolling

Comment: If it's all makes sense for you - ok, leave it

Comment: Sorry, I meant scrolling of the jq filter.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this could be achieved. When grabbing values from child arrays to generate values, I like using `foreach` for this purpose.

```
$ jq -r '.results[] | foreach .indicators[] as $i ({name}; .;
    [.name,$i.type,$i.indicator]
) | @csv'
```

Comment: This `foreach` solution carries quite a lot of unnecessary computational overhead, and although an explicit looping construct sometimes has its appeal, here it goes against the jq grain, as evinced by the syntactic complexity and the subtlety required for the handling of `.name`.

Comment: Sure I agree, certainly for this particular case. Though it does make managing the properties you want to propagate a lot easier and does it all within a single expression which is what I'm going for.